# Python AWS Glue log says "Considering file without prefix as a python extra file" for uploaded python zip packages

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

In AWS Glue, for a simple pandas job of reading data in XLSX and writing to CSV. I have a small code. As per the Python Glue instructions, I have zipped the required libraries and provided the as packages to Glue Job while execution.

**Question:** What do the following logs convey?

```
Considering file without prefix as a python extra file s3://raw-data/sampath/scripts/s3fs/fsspec.zip
Considering file without prefix as a python extra file s3://raw-data/sampath/scripts/s3fs/jmespath.zip
Considering file without prefix as a python extra file s3://raw-data/sampath/scripts/s3fs/s3fs.zip
....
```

please elaborate with an example?

Comment: Is it spark or python shell job? in spark job, you can't use pandas as it is not native python library but C/C++

Comment: Its a simple Python shell job

Answer (score 5):

In python shell jobs, you should add external libraries in egg file and not zip file. Zip file is for Spark job.

I also wrote small shell script to deploy python shell job without manual steps to create egg file and upload to s3 and deploy via cloudformation. Script does all automatically. You may find code at https://github.com/fatangare/aws-python-shell-deploy. Script will take csv file and convert it into excel file using pandas and xlswriter libraries.